# Android multiple viewpager with fixed views

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager, gallery, swipe

I have to create a view pager activity and each page has the layout below

- Fixed Layout
- View Pager for main image
- Text description
- View Pager with multiple images
- Fixed Layout

I am able to achieve a fixed header and footer from the below link
http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/android-fixed-header-and-footer-with-scrollable-content-layout-example

But my need is the text description space should be unswipeable by itself, it should move to next page only on swiping the main image.

The bottom view pager should show 3 images and on clicking on any image it should show in large view in main image like a gallery layout.

Swiping on bottom view pager should show next set of 3 images in same array and it should not hurt the main image. But swiping on main image should move all 3 contents(both view pagers and text view) to next array.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you post the screenshot or image of what you want to implement

Comment: @user765 have uploaded my image to photobucket. Cant post images here now. Here is the link http://i820.photobucket.com/albums/zz126/sskumar21/display_zpsxlkbneuw.jpg

Comment: okay..seems easy..design your layout exactly as in the image...add 2 viewpagers and set pageradapters to them as per your requirement..make sure you set adapter to both the pagers..when the main page swipes you can change the textview in the instantiateitem() of the adapter..try if this works..